# JavaScript - for loop not working with setCustomValidity

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I made a simple HTML `form` and want to make custom validation of it. I am using `for` loop for checking all my reg expressions, but it stops after first checking regardless of true or false in `if` statement. Where did I make a mistake?

### index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-1q8mTJOASx8j1Au+a5WDVnPi2lkFfwwEAa8hDDdjZlpLegxhjVME1fgjWPGmkzs7" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" integrity="sha384-fLW2N01lMqjakBkx3l/M9EahuwpSfeNvV63J5ezn3uZzapT0u7EYsXMjQV+0En5r" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <meta name="udacity-grader" content="https://udacity.github.io/course-web-forms/lesson2/quizCustomValidity/grader/tests.json" libraries="jsgrader" unit-tests="https://udacity.github.io/course-web-forms/lesson2/quizCustomValidity/grader/unit_tests.js">
    <title>Quiz - setCustomValidity</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h3>Create a new password</h3>
        <p>Password should meet the following requirements:</p>
        <ul>
            <li>16-100 characters (longer is better)</li>
            <li>At least one of these symbols: !, @, #, $, %, ^, &, *</li>
            <li>At least one number</li>
            <li>At least one lowercase letter</li>
            <li>At least one uppercase letter</li>
        </ul>        
        <form class="form-inline">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only">New password</label> 
                <input class="form-control" id="first" type="text" maxlength="100" placeholder="New password" autofocus>    
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label class="sr-only">Repeat password</label> 
                <input class="form-control" id="second" type="text" minlenght="16" maxlength="100" placeholder="Repeat password"> 
            </div>
            <button class="btn btn-default" id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
        </form>
    </div> <!-- container -->
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-0mSbJDEHialfmuBBQP6A4Qrprq5OVfW37PRR3j5ELqxss1yVqOtnepnHVP9aJ7xS" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <script src="app.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

### app.js

```
var firstPasswordInput = document.querySelector('#first');
var secondPasswordInput = document.querySelector('#second');
var submit = document.querySelector('#submit');
var constraint = new RegExp;
var constraints = [
  [/[\!\@\#\$\%\^\&\*]/g, "No match one of the required symbols"],
  [/\d/g, "No match a number"],
  [/[a-z]/g, "No match a lowercase letter"],
  [/[A-Z]/g, "No match an uppercase letter"],
];

function checkPass () {
  for (var i in constraints) {
    constraint = constraints[i];
    
    console.log(constraint[0]);         
    console.log(constraint[0].test(firstPasswordInput.value));
    console.log(firstPasswordInput.value);
    console.log("\n");
  
    if (constraint[0].test(firstPasswordInput.value)) {
      firstPasswordInput.setCustomValidity('');
    } else {
      firstPasswordInput.setCustomValidity(constraint[1]);
      firstPasswordInput.checkValidity();
      return 1;
    }  
  }  
  return 0;
}

window.onload = function () {
    firstPasswordInput.oninput = checkPass;
}
```

### live demo:

https://googledrive.com/host/0B5kseRGPxGVEbWN6RzJReTB4RWc

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kqw60k1k/1/

Comment: `firstPasswordInput.oninput = checkPass;` not `firstPasswordInput.oninput = checkPass();`

Comment: Thanks, I've fixed it, but it is still not working.

Comment: see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/kqw60k1k/2/

Comment: I get true in if statement, but I still have error validation message https://googledrive.com/host/0B5kseRGPxGVEbWN6RzJReTB4RWc/err.JPG

Comment: Using the example of typing the letter t into the first password box.  This does return false for constraint[0].test(firstPasswordInput.value)) and because you return out of the loop no more regex are tested.  If you then type ! this will return true for your first regex and then proceed to the next regex which will return false.  So two regex will be checked.  You can keep going depending on what you insert into the text box.  For this function that seems correct as you would exit the loop as soon as the first regex fails.  What exactly are you wanting that this function doesn't do for you?

Comment: If you do want all of the regex expressions to be checked and more than one fails, which error message would you want to display?

Comment: It should display first error, but my problem was that I got an error message from a previously passed regex. Now I have solution. Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are multiple problems, like using the global flag in the regex so try

```js
var firstPasswordInput = document.querySelector('#first');
var secondPasswordInput = document.querySelector('#second');
var form = document.querySelector('form');
var submit = document.querySelector('#submit');
var constraint = new RegExp;
var constraints = [
  [/[!@#$%^&*]/, "No match one of the required symbols"],
  [/\d/, "No match a number"],
  [/[a-z]/, "No match a lowercase letter"],
  [/[A-Z]/, "No match an uppercase letter"],
];

function checkPass(isSubmit) {
  firstPasswordInput.setCustomValidity('');
  constraints.some(function(constraint) {
    if (!constraint[0].test(firstPasswordInput.value)) {
      firstPasswordInput.setCustomValidity(constraint[1]);
      return true;
    }
  });
  if (!firstPasswordInput.checkValidity()) {
    !isSubmit && submit.click();
    return false;
  } else {
    return true;
  }
}

window.onload = function() {
  firstPasswordInput.oninput = checkPass;
  form.onsubmit = function(){
   return checkPass(true);
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<link href="http://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.6/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <h3>Create a new password</h3>
  <p>Password should meet the following requirements:</p>
  <ul>
    <li>16-100 characters (longer is better)</li>
    <li>At least one of these symbols: !, @, #, $, %, ^, &, *</li>
    <li>At least one number</li>
    <li>At least one lowercase letter</li>
    <li>At least one uppercase letter</li>
  </ul>
  <form class="form-inline">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="sr-only">New password</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="first" type="text" maxlength="100" placeholder="New password" autofocus>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label class="sr-only">Repeat password</label>
      <input class="form-control" id="second" type="text" minlenght="16" maxlength="100" placeholder="Repeat password">
    </div>
    <button class="btn btn-default" id="submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
<!-- container -->
```